# Disks with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: statistics, monte-carlo, statistical-mechanics, python

I have a Monte Carlo simulation program for hard disks with periodic boundary conditions, but I cannot understand how it works and what exactly is doing.
Can someone helps me?

Here is the program:

import pylab

def show_conf(L, sigma, title, fname):

pylab.axes()

for [x, y] in L:

for ix in range(-1, 2):

for iy in range(-1, 2):

cir = pylab.Circle((x + ix, y + iy), radius=sigma,  fc='r')

pylab.gca().add_patch(cir)

pylab.axis('scaled')

pylab.title(title)

pylab.axis([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0])

pylab.savefig(fname)

pylab.show()

pylab.close()

L = [[0.9, 0.9]]

sigma = 0.4

show_conf(L, sigma, 'test graph', 'one_disk.png')

Comment: It looks like almost everything you've shown us is graphing code; the only other thing that this code does is make a bunch of circle objects to prepare to draw them. There is no "Monte Carlo" or even "simulation" aspect to this program as given.

Comment: Yes, it is the beginning, but I cannot understand how many and how does the pogram draw the circles. I see that we have the square 1X1, but I do not understand how the program draw four parts of circles and why.

Comment: Well, your loop builds a circle with a different center for each ix and each iy in the given ranges (so I guess 9 of them total for each element of L). Then it draws them. Your code does not tell us anything about what these circles are to be used for.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understood how stupid was my question, sorry.

Comment: It looks like code from an exercise of week 3 for a course on statistical mechanics: https://www.coursera.org/learn/statistical-mechanics . From the problem description, working with it should improve your grasp of python needed for simulations of statistical mechanics. In the 2023 edition of the course this is guided by detailed questions.
1. Which geometrical object does it draw?
2. What is the color of the object, and where is it specified?
3. How does it implement periodic boundary conditions?
Etc. 
In short it works through you studying the code and looking up stuff in documentation.